# error when connecting database to the form , and give me the below error

Tags: php

I am try to fill the form and I got this error. Please someone tell me why?
I have attached all the code and the images: what I want is when I fill this form, it gets automatically saved in database. And please, if you can provide me how to upload images from the same form to the same database at `phpmyadmin`.

**Error Message:**

[image]

This is the model :

```
 class Clinic_Model extends CI_Model 
 {
  function insert_into_db()
    {
    $pfn = $_POST['pfn'];
    $pe = $_POST['pe'];
    $pmn = $_POST['pmn'];
    $pa = $_POST['pa'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];
    $ph = $_POST['ph'];
    $pgt = $_POST['pgt'];
    $pbp = $_POST['pbp'];
    $pec = $_POST['pec'];

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO add_clinic 
    VALUES($pfn','$pe','$pmn','$pa','$pw','$ph','$pgt','$pbp','$pec')");

}
}

  <?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

This is the controller

```
class Easyclinic extends CI_Controller {

   //----------Constructor----------
  public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    //load Model
    $this->load->model('clinic_model');

   }
  //----------BaseFunctions----------
   public function index()
    {    
    $this->load->view('add_patient');
    }
    public function mydata()
    {
    $this->load->view('mydata');
   }
   public function addpatient()
   {
    $this->load->view('add_patient');
   }    

     //---------Advinced Functions---------

    public function insert_into_db()
    {
    $this->load->model('clinic_model');
    $this->clinic_model->insert_into_db();
    $this->load->view('success');//loading success view
   }



     }
```

this is the view

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Add Patient</title>
  <!-- for-mobile-apps -->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="keywords" content="easyclinic" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", 
    function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
    function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
   <!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
   <!-- //custom-theme -->
      <link href="assests/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="all" />
 <!-- js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> 
 </script>
  <!-- //js -->

   <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
   family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   </head>
  <body>
  <!-- banner -->
 <div class="center-container">
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="w3layouts_head">Add Patient Info</h1>
        <h1 class="w3layouts_head">Welcome Dr.Atef</h1>
            <div class="w3layouts_main_grid">


                <form action="<?php echo base_url();? 
         >easyclinic/insert_into_db" method="post" class="w3_form_post">


     <!-- day/time -->
        <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid w3ls_main_grid">
          <span class="agileinfo_grid">
            <label>Examination Date</label>
            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridl">
              <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" name="Text" 
        type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if 
       (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridr">
              <input type="time" name="Time" placeholder=" " required="">
            </div>
              <div class="clear"> </div>
          </span>
        </div>

       <!--  name -->


        <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
          <span class="agileits_grid">
            <label>Patient Full Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="pfn" placeholder=" 4 part name" 
        required="">
          </span>
        </div>
     <!-- email  -->
        <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
          <span class="agileits_grid">
            <label>Patient Email </label>
            <input type="text" name="pe" placeholder=" Email" required="">
          </span>
        </div>
    <!-- Phone number -->
        <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
          <span class="agileits_grid">
            <label>Patient Number </label>
            <input type="text" name="pmn" placeholder="Phone Number" 
      required="">
            </span>
        </div>
       <!-- choose your Gender-->
      <div class="content-w3ls">
        <div class="form-w3ls">
          <div class="content-wthree2">
            <div class="grid-w3layouts1">
              <div class="w3-agile1">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a-option" name="pg">
                    <label for="a-option">Male </label>
                    <div class="check"></div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b-option" name="pg2">
                    <label for="b-option">female</label>
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </div>
        <!--  age -->
            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
              <span class="agileits_grid">
                <label>Patient Age </label>
                <input type="text" name="pa" placeholder="Patient Age" 
       required="">
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--  weight -->

            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
              <span class="agileits_grid">
                <label>Weight</label>
                <input type="text" name="pw" placeholder="Weight in 
       KiloGrams" required="">
              </span>
            </div>
       <!--  Height -->

            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
              <span class="agileits_grid">
                <label>Height</label>
                <input type="text" name="ph" placeholder="Height in 
       CentiMeters" required="">
              </span>
            </div>
    <!--  Glucose -->

            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
             <span class="agileits_grid">
               <label>Glucose Test</label>
               <input type="text" name="pgt" placeholder="~100~140" 
         required="">
             </span>
            </div>

        <!--  Heart pressure -->
            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
              <span class="agileits_grid">
                <label>Blood Pressure</label>
                <input type="text" name="pbp" placeholder="~120~180" 
           required="">
              </span>
            </div>
           <!-- Uoload File -->
        <div>
        <span class="agileits_grid">  
        <label>Upload sonar image</label>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload"> 
        </br>
              Choose a file: 
        <input type="image" name="usi" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
           <!-- Uoload File -->
        <div>
        <span class="agileits_grid">  
        <label>Upload cbc image</label>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
              Choose a file: 
        <input type="image" name="uci" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </div>

         <!-- day/time -->

        <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid w3ls_main_grid">
          <span class="agileinfo_grid">
            <label>Expectation of Childbirth</label>
            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridl">
              <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" name="Text" 
             type="text" value="mm/dd/yyyy" onfocus="this.value = '';" 
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridr">
              <input type="time" name="pec" placeholder=" " required="">
            </div>
              <div class="clear"> </div>
          </span>
        </div>  


             <!-- submit button -->

                <div class="w3_main_grid">
                    <div class="w3_main_grid_right">
                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>




          <!-- Calendar -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                    });
                </script>
        <!-- //Calendar -->



        <div class="w3layouts_copy_right">
            <div class="container">
                <p>© 2018 Patient Registration Form. All rights reserved |  
        <a href="http://w3layouts.com">HassanAli</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
             <!-- //footer -->
                </body>
                    </html>
```

and this is the image of phpmyadmion: 
[see phpmyadmin iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olR7m.png)

Comment: Your missing a opening quote in `VALUES($pfn','$pe'`

Comment: well i edited and then i got this
Error Number: 1136

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

INSERT INTO add_clinic VALUES('Hassan ali ','hassanaliraafat@gmail.com','01000450292','20','30','20','30','120','15:52')

Filename: C:/wamp/www/easyclinic/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor error of a missing ' in your columns of the INSERT statement (`VALUES($pfn'`), but also there is also a problem of matching the columns up.  I would normally list the columns that I am inserting into as well, something like...

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO add_clinic (`Patient Full Name`, *** )
    VALUES('$pfn','$pe','$pmn','$pa','$pw','$ph','$pgt','$pbp','$pec')");
```

(Where *** is just a list of the columns to be inserted into).

There are two recommendations I would like to make - firstly is to change the names of your columns.  Having spaces in column names can cause all sorts of problems and is not normally recommended.

Secondly is to look into using prepared statements and bind variables, this will provide all sorts of benefits later, including security and not having problems with certain characters in the text.

Comment: function insert_into_db()
 {
  $pfn = $_POST['pfn'];
  $pe = $_POST['pe'];
  $pmn = $_POST['pmn'];
  $pa = $_POST['pa'];
  $pw = $_POST['pw'];
  $ph = $_POST['ph'];
  $pgt = $_POST['pgt'];
  $pbp = $_POST['pbp'];
  $pec = $_POST['pec'];

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO add_clinic (`pfn`, `pe`, `pmn`,`pa`,`pw`,`ph`,`pgt`,`pbp`,`pec` )
 VALUES('$pfn','$pe','$pmn','$pa','$pw','$ph','$pgt','$pbp','$pec')");

what esle should i do thanks nigel ren

Comment: Are your database columns called `pfn`, your image of your table definition seems to have `Patient Full Name`.